# Chaining infix operators with statically resolved type parameter

Tags: f#, inline

I'm trying to create an infix operator to make `System.Text.StringBuilder` slightly easier to use.

I have the following inline function using statically resolved type parameters:

```
let inline append value builder = (^T : (member Append : _ -> ^T) (builder, value))
```

which handles all the overloads of `StringBuilder.Append`. This works fine as a regular function:

```
StringBuilder()
|> append 1
|> append " hello "
|> append 2m
|> string
// Result is: '1 hello 2'
```

When I try to use define an infix operator like so:

```
let inline (<<) builder value = append value builder
```

it works when all parameters in a chain are of the same type:

```
StringBuilder()
<< 1
<< 2
<< 3
|> string
// Result is: '123'
```

but fails with parameters of different types:

```
StringBuilder()
<< 1
<< "2"  // <- Syntax error, expected type 'int' but got 'string'.
<< 123m // <- Syntax error, expected type 'int' but got 'decimal'.
```

The expected type seems to be inferred by the first usage of the `<<` operator in the chain. I would assume that each `<<` would be applied separately.

If the chain is split into separate steps the compiler is happy again:

```
let b0 = StringBuilder()
let b1 = b0 << 1
let b2 = b1 << "2"
let b3 = b2 << 123m
b3 |> string
// Result is: '12123'
```

Is it possible to create such an operator?

### Edit

A hacky "solution" seems to be to pipe intermediate results through the identity function whenever the type of the argument changes:

```
StringBuilder()
<< 1    // No piping needed here due to same type (int)
<< 2    |> id
<< "A"  |> id
<< 123m
|> string
// Result is: '12A123'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can possibly add a data point to this mystery, albeit I am
only able to surmise that this behavior might have something to do with the particular overload for `value: obj`. If I uncomment that line and try to run it, the compiler says:

> ```
> Script1.fsx(21,14): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>     'a -> 'c    
> but given a
>     System.Text.StringBuilder -> System.Text.StringBuilder    
> The type ''a' does not match the type 'System.Text.StringBuilder'
> ```

This happened while trying to map the various overloads of `System.Text.StringBuilder` to statically resolved type parameters on an operator. This seems to be a fairly standard technique in similar cases, since it will produce compile-time errors for unsupported types.

```
open System.Text
type Foo = Foo with
    static member ($) (Foo, x : bool)    = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : byte)    = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : char[])  = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : char)    = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : decimal) = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : float)   = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : float32) = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : int16)   = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : int32)   = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : int64)   = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    // static member ($) (Foo, x : obj)     = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : sbyte)   = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : string)  = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : uint16)  = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : uint32)  = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x
    static member ($) (Foo, x : uint64)  = fun (b : StringBuilder) -> b.Append x

let inline (<.<) b a =
    (Foo $ a) b
// val inline ( <.< ) :
//   b:'a -> a: ^b -> 'c
//     when (Foo or  ^b) : (static member ( $ ) : Foo *  ^b -> 'a -> 'c)

let res =
    StringBuilder()
    <.< 1
    <.< 2
    <.< 3
    <.< "af"
    <.< 2.32m
    |> string
// val res : string = "123af2,32"
```

Comment: Adding the `inline` specifier to the static members avoids closures in the final result, but apart from that this works perfectly. One should, however, not add the `obj` overload as this causes the compiler to select the `StringBuilder.Append(obj)` for every parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite odd - and I would say it may be a compiler bug. The fact that you can fix this by splitting the pipeline into separate `let` bindings is what makes me think this is a bug. In fact:

```
// The following does not work
(StringBuilder() << "A") << 1

// But the following does work
(let x = StringBuilder() << "A" in x) << 1
```

I think the compiler is somehow not able to figure out that the result is again just `StringBuilder`, which can have other `Append` members. A very hacky version of your operator would be:

```
let inline (<<) builder value = 
  append value builder |> unbox<StringBuilder>
```

This performs an unsafe cast to `StringBuilder` so that the return type is always `StringBuilder`. This makes your code work (and it chooses the right `Append` overlaods), but it also lets you write code that uses `Append` on non-StringBuilder things and this code will fail at runtime.

Comment: Piping each intermediate result through `id` also works: `StringBuilder() << 1 |> id << "A" |> id << 'B' |> id << 123m` and avoids the unsafe cast. Makes for some funny looking code though.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a solution in the following:

```
let inline append value builder = (^T: (member Append: _ -> ^S) (builder, value))
let inline (<<) builder value = append value builder

let builder = new StringBuilder()
let result = 
    builder
    << 1
    << " hello "
    << 2m
    |> string
printfn "%s" result
```

As seen the return value from `Append` is set to `^S` instead of `^T` and `^S` is resolved to require `Append` as member.

It will find the correct overload for `Append` which you can see, it you use the following mockup of a `StringBuilder`:

```
type MyStringBuilder() =
    member this.Append(value: int) =
        printfn "int: %d" value;
        this
    member this.Append(value: string) =
        printfn "string: %s" value;
        this
    member this.Append(value: decimal) =
        printfn "decimal: %f" value;
        this
    member this.Append(value: obj) =
        printfn "obj: %A" value
        this

let builder = new MyStringBuilder()
let result = 
    builder
    << 1
    << " hello "
    << 2m
    |> string
```

---

Warning: There is though a peculiarity in the following setup:

```
let builder = StringBuilder()
let result = 
    builder
    << 1
    << " hello "
    << 2m
    << box " XX "
    |> string
```

when compiling this with the extra `<< box " XX "` the compiler gets lost somewhere in the process and is rather long time to compile (only when using `StringBuilder()` - not `MyStringBuilder()`) and the intellisense and coloring etc. seems to disappear - in my Visual Studio 2019 as least.

- At first, I thought it has something to do with the `box` value, but it rather seems to have something to do with the number of chained values???

Comment: While this does indeed work (replacing `^T` with `^S`) it brings the compiler to a halt when using a chain of more than 4 arguments.

Comment: @peder86: yes - I know (see my warning), but I can't explain why - in fact it makes Visual Studio to more or less crash and unresponsive to input. I hope that some of the more experienced F#-gurus can come up with an explanation. Maybe I should post my answer as a new question? To me, it's really strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The below works:

```
let inline (<<) (builder:StringBuilder) (value:'T) = builder.Append(value)

let x = StringBuilder()
        << 1
        << 2
        << 3
        << "af"
        << 2.32m
        |> string
```

I think you need to be specific about the `StringBuilder` type otherwise it will pick only one of the overloads.

Comment: The compiler has now picked the overload `StringBuilder.Append(value: obj)`.